# why is KVO not working on UIView subclass?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, key-value-observing

I have a UIView subclass which in turn has a contentView, declared as such in the public header:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain)UIVivew* contentView;
```

I'm trying to get KVO notifications whenever contentView's frame changes but the observeValueForKeyPath method is not being ever called in my UIView subclass:

```
@implementation MyView


@synthesize contentView = _contentView;


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        [self.contentView addObserver:self 
                           forKeyPath:@"frame" 
                              options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) 
                              context:nil];
    }   
    return self;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"frame"]) {
        CGRect newContentFrame = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] CGRectValue];
        CGRect selfNewFrame = self.frame;
        selfNewFrame.size = CGSizeMake(newContentFrame.size.width + 10, newContentFrame.size.height + 10);
        self.frame = selfNewFrame;
    }

    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
}
```

Any ideas as to why is KVO not firing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry... sleep deprivation I guess...

Forgot to alloc / init the contentView.

Comment: So this fixed the problem? Select it as an answer when you can - thanks!